# Where does Console.Out.Write() go for a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have added various `Console.Out.Write()` statements for debugging purposes in a Windows service application, which I run as a console app when testing. Is there any harm in leaving these statements when deploying the application as a service? (the debugging information is not sensitive, I don't care if users happen to find and see it)

Also, is there a way to view the console output of a particular service while it is running?

Comment: The harm is that your code runs slower than necessary.  You'll never see it, at least use Debug.Print() or a logging library to have the option of disabling it completely or see it when you need to because there's a problem.

Comment: @BhushanFirake Console.WriteLine() or Console.Out.WriteLine() apply. Any differences in this context I should be aware of?

Comment: @invertigo Nope...surely not. Didn't know till now if `Console.Out.Write` existed..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any harm in leaving these statements when deploying the application as a service?

It will not show you any `Exception`, if you are printing it on `Console`. This way you will be in complete darkness about errors and exceptions.

> Is there a way to view the console output of a particular service while it is running?

Yes, surely. You can view the output in the Output Window after you print it using `Debug.Print()` or `Debug.WriteLine()`.

They both do the same thing, but `Debug.Print()` will only take a string, while `Debug.WriteLine()` will accept an object which ends up calling the object's `ToString()` method.

IMHO, you should either use some kind of logging instead of printing all these. You can see logs anytime, but you will not be able to seat and see Console output all the time..!!

Comment: thanks for the information. I know there are better ways to log info, errors, etc., but that's not really what I'm looking for in this case. I am more curious if there is an absolute "need" to go through legacy code to remove cases where developers (myself included) have added the WriteLine() statements, not to catch and surface exceptions, but to print information that is only relevant while developing.

Comment: @invertigo I also add console outputs upto deployment. But once it is up I hit Ctrl+F, then replace all `Console.WriteLine`s to `Debug.Print`s..:P